# Permanently removing objects in RStudio Mac OS?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, rdata

Every time I started RStudio, I have seen this my working environment.

I can use rm(list=ls()) to remove them temporarily, but every time I  restarted RStudio, they showed up again.

I use getwd() to see my working directory, but in the working directory, I did not see any .Rdata file. How can I get rid of these things ?

Your kind help will be well regarded.

I use Mac OS 10.10.

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? Are they old variables from a familiar project or session? Did you explore `Tools > Global Options...`?

Comment: In Unix-like operating systems (like OS X), files with names starting with dot (`.`) are hidden files, so you won't see the file in the Finder. You'll have to open the terminal and look for it (see my answer below)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post pictures since my reputation is not enough. They are clearly from former projects. @jaysunice3401

Answer (score 3):

Click on RStudio in the menu bar and go to Preferences. 
In the R General section, unclick the Restore .RData into workspace at startup option. 
The default is to reload the working environment when you restart RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you, at some point, chose to save your environment to your working directory (most likely `~`, i.e. your home directory, which is the default RStudio working directory).

The easier way to clear your default environment is to remove the `.RData` file from your home directory. It will not appear in any Finder window, because in a Unix-like OS (like OS X), files starting with `.` are hidden. So do the following:

1. Open a terminal window
2. If not already there, go to your home folder: `cd ~`
3. Check if there's an `.RData` file: `ls -lA .RData`
4. If the file exists delete it: `rm .RData` (if you want, create a backup: `cp .RData ./RData_backup)

Comment: I guess it might be simpler to remove all the objects through `rm(list=ls())` and then saving your workspace before exit.